# Logback pattern exception after converting from log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

I am currently moving from log4j to logback and i converted my log4j.properties file using the converter they offer in the logback homepage. But i am getting some weird error on my pattern that i cant figure out what it wants me to do:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!-- For assistance related to logback-translator or configuration  -->
> <!-- files in general, please contact the logback user mailing list -->
> <!-- at http://www.qos.ch/mailman/listinfo/logback-user             -->
> <!--                                                                -->
> <!-- For professional support please see                            -->
> <!--    http://www.qos.ch/shop/products/professionalSupport         --> 
> <!--                                                                -->
> <configuration>
> <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
> <encoder>
>   <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%p] [%C{1},%M(),%L] - %m%n</pattern>
> </encoder>
> </appender>
> <appender name="R" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
> <!--See also http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender-->
> <File>/log/debug.log</File>
> <encoder>
>   <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %15.15t [%p] [%C{1},%M():%L] - %m%n</pattern>
> </encoder>
> <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
>   <maxIndex>1</maxIndex>
>   <FileNamePattern>/log/debug.log.%i</FileNamePattern>
> </rollingPolicy>
> <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
>   <MaxFileSize>100KB</MaxFileSize>
> </triggeringPolicy>
> </appender>
> <root level="debug">
> <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
> <appender-ref ref="R"/>
> </root>
> </configuration>
> ```

and here is the error i am getting:

> 18:02:29,368 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@17f9a29 - Failed to instantiate converter class [ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.MethodOfCallerConverter] as a composite converter for keyword [M] ch.qos.logback.core.util.IncompatibleClassException
>       at ch.qos.logback.core.util.IncompatibleClassException
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:62)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:48)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:35)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler.createCompositeConverter(Compiler.java:135)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:47)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.compile(Parser.java:91)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.PatternLayoutBase.start(PatternLayoutBase.java:86)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder.start(PatternLayoutEncoder.java:28)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA.end(NestedComplexPropertyIA.java:167)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:317)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:196)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:182)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
>       at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
>       at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
>       at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
>       at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
>       at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
>       at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
>       at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
>       at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
>       at  at taxonomyParser.(taxonomyParser.java:34)
>   18:02:29,368 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@17f9a29 - Failed to create converter for [%M] keyword

I dont understand it because on the documentation page they clearly say that %M is the modifier for Method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the pattern, the parenthesis are special.

Where you coded `%M()`, try `%M\(\)`.

See at [Logback Layouts](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#Parentheses)